# How to split strings in a column and convert the values to integers

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I´m working with a dataset that looks something like this and I´m interested in seeing how blood pressure affect some patients.

```
df = {'Person ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
      'BMI': ['Overweight','Normal','Normal','Obese','Obese','Underweight','Normal','Obese'], 
      'Sleep Disorder': ['Insomnia',float('nan'),float('nan'),'Sleep Apnea','Sleep Apnea',float('nan'),float('nan'),'Insomnia'],
'Illness':['Ill', 'Healthy','Healthy','Ill','Ill','Healthy','Healthy','Ill'],
'Blood Pressure': ['125/82','132/87','128/85','126/83','126/83','115/78','139/91','142/92']}
```

Output:

```
   Person ID          BMI Sleep Disorder  Illness Blood Pressure   Sleep Duration
0          1   Overweight       Insomnia      Ill         125/82              6.1
1          2       Normal            NaN  Healthy         132/87              6.2
2          3       Normal            NaN  Healthy         128/85              6.2
3          4        Obese    Sleep Apnea      Ill         126/83              5.9
4          5        Obese    Sleep Apnea      Ill         126/83              5.9
5          6  Underweight            NaN  Healthy         115/78              8.1
6          7       Normal            NaN  Healthy         139/91              8.1
7          8        Obese       Insomnia      Ill         142/92              8.1
```

The main problem is that the `Blood Pressure` is not an Int neither a Float so how can I measure a correlation or which kind of correlation can be used to compare `"Ill"` and `"Healthy"` people?

The idea is to replicate this:

```
graph_bp = sns.scatterplot(data = sleep_dataset, x = "Blood Pressure", y = "Sleep Duration", hue = "Health State")
graph_bp.set_title("Relation between age and sleep duration")
graph_bp.set_xlabel("Blood Pressure")
graph_bp.set_ylabel("Sleep Duration")
cor_bp = sleep_dataset["Blood Pressure"].corr(sleep_dataset["Sleep Duration"])
print("Correlation with age: " + str(cor_bp))
```

To obtain some information about Blood Pressure, but there´s no int associated.
One idea is to separate the values of highest and lowest and do the difference, but it doesn´t seem a good idea as it would say that a person with 140/100 is the same as a 100/60, how would you do a graphic out of this?

Comment: Blood pressure is simply measured in two numbers (high/low aka systolic/diastolic). If you want to represent it as one number, you'll definitely lose some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation could be either with one of the number, or both. From a scientific point of view, you should compute both correlations independently, or find a meaningful indicator that is derived from the combination of both (much harder).

Imagine that a given disease affects only one of the pressures, or affects them in opposite ways. By using an aggregation, you will lose information and potentially miss what you're looking for.

In any case, you should convert the string to two numbers, which you can achieve with:

```
df[['systolic', 'diastolic']] = (df['Blood Pressure']
                                 .str.split('/', expand=True)
                                 .astype(int)
                                )
```

Output:

```
   Person ID          BMI Sleep Disorder  Illness Blood Pressure  systolic  diastolic
0          1   Overweight       Insomnia      Ill         125/82       125         82
1          2       Normal            NaN  Healthy         132/87       132         87
2          3       Normal            NaN  Healthy         128/85       128         85
3          4        Obese    Sleep Apnea      Ill         126/83       126         83
4          5        Obese    Sleep Apnea      Ill         126/83       126         83
5          6  Underweight            NaN  Healthy         115/78       115         78
6          7       Normal            NaN  Healthy         139/91       139         91
7          8        Obese       Insomnia      Ill         142/92       142         92
```

Then you can then graph one of the pressures:

```
graph_bp = sns.scatterplot(data=sleep_dataset, x='systolic',
                           y='Sleep Duration', hue='Illness')
```

[image]

Or both pressures:

```
df_melt = sleep_dataset.melt(df.columns.difference(['systolic', 'diastolic']),
                             var_name='type', value_name='pressure')
graph_bp = sns.scatterplot(data=df_melt, x='pressure',
                           y='Sleep Duration', hue='Illness', style='type')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the .split() I didn´t knew that function!